# Execute a command on Kubernetes node from the master

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to execute a command on a node from the master. For e.g let's say I have worker node: kubenode01

Now a pod (pod-test) is running on this node. Using "kubectl get pods --output=wide" on the master shows that the pod is running on this node.
Trying to execute a command on that pod from the master results into an error e.g:

*`kubectl exec -ti pod-test -- cat /etc/resolv.conf`*

The result is:

*`Error from server: error dialing backend: dial tcp 10.0.22.131:10250: i/o timeout`*

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You can execute `kubectl` commands from anywhere as long as your [`kubeconfig`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/) is configured to point to the right cluster URL ([kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/)), with the right credentials and the firewall allows connecting to the kube-apiserver port.

In your case, I'd check if your *`10.0.22.131:10250`* is the real *`IP:PORT`* for your kube-apiserver and that you can access it.

Note that *`kubectl exec -ti pod-test -- cat /etc/resolv.conf`* runs on the *Pod* and not on the Node. If you'd like to run on the Node just simply use [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell).

Update:

There are two other alternatives here:

1. You can create a pod (or debug pod) with a [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) that specifically makes that pod run on the specific node.
2. If you are trying to debug something on a pod already running on a specific node, you can also try creating a [debug ephemeral container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container).

On newer versions of Kubernetes you can use a debug pod to run something on a specific node

✌️

Comment: I believe he is asking about executing a command on a node not a pod.

Comment: Yes but i removed the downvote - FYI i found a way to run against a node by automate creating a debug pod for the node and then run a command in it.

Comment: Thanks let me expand the answer.  Also, there is a newer feature called ephemeral debug container.